# How to get user orders by date in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I'm looking for a standard way of getting a user total sum of orders in a date range or for current month.

After exploring woocommerce source code, what I got is, woo is using something like this

```
            $order_item_amounts = $this->get_order_report_data( array(
            'data' => array(
                '_line_total' => array(
                    'type'            => 'order_item_meta',
                    'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
                    'function' => 'SUM',
                    'name'     => 'order_item_amount'
                ),
                'post_date' => array(
                    'type'     => 'post_data',
                    'function' => '',
                    'name'     => 'post_date'
                ),
                '_product_id' => array(
                    'type'            => 'order_item_meta',
                    'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
                    'function'        => '',
                    'name'            => 'product_id'
                ),
            ),
            'where_meta' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'type'       => 'order_item_meta',
                    'meta_key'   => array( '_product_id', '_variation_id' ),
                    'meta_value' => $this->product_ids,
                    'operator'   => 'IN'
                ),
            ),
            'group_by'     => 'product_id, ' . $this->group_by_query,
            'order_by'     => 'post_date ASC',
            'query_type'   => 'get_results',
            'filter_range' => true
        ) );
```

in class-wc-report-sales-by-product.php

But as you know, this works based on products not users.
from the above code,
 `$this->group_by_query` part holds the conditions for dates which can be found in woo source. My question is actually about how to use a builtin function of woocommerce to generate a list of orders based on given date range.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[From your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979770/how-to-get-total-sum-of-orders-by-a-user-in-woocommerce/35146568#35146568), which I believe is correct.

You just need to add the [`date_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) in the fields... something like this:

```
public function get_customer_total_order() {
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => - 1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => array( 'shop_order' ),
        'post_status' => array( 'wc-completed' ),
        'date_query' => array(
            'after' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-10 days')),
            'before' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today')) 
        )
        
    ) );

    $total = 0;
    foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order );
        $total += $order->get_total();
    }

    return $total;
}
```

Additional Readings:

[DATE FORMATS](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)

inline with the question on how to use `get_order_report_data`, you can do it this way... you can paste this in your `functions.php` on the theme to test.

```
include_once WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/woocommerce/includes/admin/reports/class-wc-admin-report.php';

$reports = new WC_Admin_Report();
$args = array(
    'data' => array(
        '_order_total' => array(
            'type'     => 'meta',
            'function' => 'SUM',
            'name'     => 'total_sales'
        ),
    ),
    'where' => array(
        array(
            'key'      => 'post_date',
            'value'    => date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( '01/01/2016' ) ), // starting date
            'operator' => '>'
        ),
        array(
            'key'      => 'post_date',
            'value'    => date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( '02/01/2016' ) ), // end date...
            'operator' => '<'
        ),
    ),
    'where_meta' => array(
        array(
            'meta_key'   => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value' => '1', // customer id
            'operator'   => '='
        )
    ),
);
$data = $reports->get_order_report_data($args);
print_r($data); // prints like: stdClass Object ( [total_sales] => 200 )
```

Please take note of the comments in the codes above...

Comment: thanks for your answer, it's correct. Actually I implemented this approach a few mins ago when I remembered Wordpress date_query. It's a good way. But is there any other method doing all by just one query something like get_order_report_data()