# Change user role based on WooCommerce yearly orders count

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I'm trying to implement a feature where customers receive a new user role after a certain amount of orders have been made, but all those orders must have been made within the same year.

I was able to assign the user role based on nth number of orders but can't seem to go beyond to where the date needs to be taken into consideration, can someone point me in the right direction or point out what I might be missing.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
function change_user_role_on_order_status_completed( $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    $user_id = $order->user_id;

    $order_this_year = false;

    $current_date = date('Y');

    $total_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => $user_id,
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
    ) );

    if ( $total_orders > 1 ) {
        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item_values):

            // Get the item date
            if ($item_date = $item_values->get_date_completed()->format ('Y') == $current_date) {
                $order_this_year = true;
            }

        endforeach;

        if ($order_this_year) {
            $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );

            // Set role editor
            $user->set_role( 'customer_club' ); 
        }

    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'change_user_role_on_order_status_completed', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35146971/1117368

Comment: Hi, just checked totally different from what i'm trying to do, basically I have two condition which needs to pass in order for the user role to change, first the customer must have more that let's say 5 orders and those orders must have been made in the same year to qualify for a user role change, hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `WC_Order_Query` here is a much lighter and simple way to change the user role based on yearly orders count:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'change_user_role_on_order_status_completed', 10, 2 );
function change_user_role_on_order_status_completed( $order_id, $order ) {
    // Here set the minimal order count
    $min_orders_count = 3;

    // The WC_Order_Query
    $queried_orders = wc_get_orders( array(
        'limit'        => -1,
        'customer_id'  => $order->get_customer_id(),
        'date_paid'    => '>=' . date('Y') . '-01-01', // or 'date_created'
        'return'       => 'ids'
    ) );

    if ( sizeof($queried_orders) >= $min_orders_count ) {
        // Get an instance of the customer WP_User Object
        $user = $order->get_user();

        // Change the user role
        $user->set_role( 'customer_club' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it does not work also tried variations and a different theme but still didn't work any ideas why?

Comment: @star_gazer Just retested this code, it works perfectly (and this has nothing to do with the theme). The code is triggered each time on Order completed notification and the current order will be included in the queried orders count.

Comment: Yeah I know it has nothing to do with the theme just wanted to make sure on my end, the based on the code it should be working it's just not changing the user role in the back-end, which is odd even with all the conditions being met.

Comment: @star_gazer I have tried  with ADD ROLE `$user->add_role( 'customer_club' );` and it's adding the role. So it should work the same way with SET ROLE

Comment: it seems to be working just running test based on the different conditions, I use the date_created, I'm not sure but I think I should be able to query on completed status will check. Thank you really appreciate the help.